# connect to Wonderware Historian OLE DB using python 3 and OSX or Linux

Tags: python, wonderware

Could anyone share a functional connection method to Wonderware's Historian using python3 on OSX (or linux)?

Historian is apparently a Microsoft SQL Server OLE DB (see pg102 of http://www.logic-control.com/datasheets/1/Historian/HistorianConcepts.pdf).

Another SO post suggests that the only python library available capable of connecting to an OLE DB is 'adodbapi' ([Connecting to Microsoft SQL server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725862/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-python))

an attempt in code (using default RO credentials):

```
import adodbapi
ServerName = "ServerName"
MSQLDatabase = "Runtime"
username = "aaUser"
password = "pwUser"
conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=INSQL;Data Source={0};Database={1};trusted_connection=yes;UID={2};PWD{3};".format(ServerName,MSQLDatabase,username,password))
```

That gives an error:

```
adodbapi.apibase.OperationalError: (InterfaceError("Windows COM Error: Dispatch('ADODB.Connection') failed.",)...
```

The error is probably due to the absence and unavailability of the pywin32 package, which is apparently Windows only ([Pywin32 (com objects) on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233461/pywin32-com-objects-on-mac))

Tips appreciated.  I highly suspect that the Microsoft vs Mac/Linux worlds just can't be bridged in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to access an MS SQL Server database (e.g. Wonderware Historian database) with Python.

Things to check:

- For ODBC, "Trusted Connection" setting should be "No". Trusted connection means that it tries to use Windows Authentication to log in. You want to use a username and password instead. I think for OLE DB you set "Integrated Security = SSPI" instead.
- Connection String (Username, Server Hostname/IP, Database name, Correct Port, Syntax)
- Port (make sure you use the correct port - may be a non-standard port)
- Firewalls - make sure that any firewalls are set up to allow access
- If you're using the hostname, make sure DNS is working (e.g. can you ping the server?)
- You may need to install an ODBC driver for Linux and pyodbc. ODBC is a more open standard. As you've pointed out, OLEDB is COM-based (e.g. Windows-based) so I'm not sure if it would be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to access a Wonderware server using Python3 both through sqlalchemy and pyodbc on Linux and Windows - I don't have a Mac so you're on your own there. I've read that there are other drivers available, but I don't have any experience with them. If you have any suggestions here I'd be glad to hear them.

This is how I modularize the functionality of pyodbc. Essentially, I've defined a function in our code that sets up the sql engine conncetion:

```
def get_conn():
    conn_pyodbc = pyodbc.connect(DSN=<myDSN>, UID=<user>, PWD=<pass>)
    return conn_pyodbc
```

And I use the connection as such:

```
def executeQuery(sql_query):
    with get_conn() as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)
```

Using the context manager just seems like an easier way of handling opening and closing database connections.

As far as setting up the DSN, I needed to install the Microsoft ODBC driver, which was easy enough to do by following some links I found online. After a successful installation I edited the /etc/odbc.init and /etc/odbcinst.ini files manually such that they look like this now:

```
$ cat /etc/odbc.ini 
[myDSN]
Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Description=Awesome server
Trace=No
Server=<serverIP>
```

and

```
$ cat odbcinst.ini 
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.1
UsageCount=1
```

In my experience, you can use 'Trusted Connection', but that means that your computer will try to connect to the server using it's Windows credentials. These work if you are logged into a Windows machine that has access to the data in question. Running on Linux is a different story, so I keep to the user/password combo.

Anymore questions feel free to ask.